# Creating array of objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an array of objects in Java and am having a few issues doing this, I want the array to be created on a existing type I have already set up and the number of arra objects I want to create will be declared using a global interger.

```
   task = new TaskSim(taskDelay, taskPeriod);
```

I want to create an array of the above object, the values of taskDelay and taskPeriod will be the same for each element within the array, which will be passed through the constructor. However the number of elements I want to create will be defined using a global int.

TaskSim is an is a class I implement to create a task object as show above , so my question here is how do i create an array of task, that have the parameters as shown above.

Comment: Is there a reason you wish to do this so primitively? There are so many better ways of doing this. Consider http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html or even Guava!  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TaskSim[] instances = new TaskSim[numberOfElements];
for (int i=0; i<instances.length; i++) {
    instances[i] = new TaskSim(taskDelay, taskPeriod);
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: This isn't created ab instance of task tough is it?

Comment: I beg your pardon? Or to put it another way: what?

Comment: I'm lost for some reason, in the code above I use task = new TaskSim etc.....

Comment: Okay, well that code creates a single instance, not an array of instances. What is your question?

Comment: How to create an array from what your answer suggets that just creates an array of TaskSim objects, if I was to delete the line that says task = new TaskSim() would your answer work?

Comment: The code in my answer does not have that line; the code in my answer is all you need to create an array of `TaskSim`.

Comment: yes but TaskSim is of type task

Comment: I don't follow. Are you saying that `TaskSim extends Task` or `TaskSim implements Task`? I'm not a mind reader; your question mentions nothing about a type other than `TaskSim`. You haven't shown any of the class definition; what do you expect me to know?

Comment: Sorry I have a class named TaskSim, and at the top of my class I am talking about here. I use private TaskSim task; I believe this extends TaskSim.

Comment: `private TaskSim task;` does **not** extend task. It declares a variable of type `TaskSim` named `task`. Just to make sure we're on the same page, [the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) describes what "extend" means. Please make sure you are using the term correctly.

Comment: Yes sorry I extends it by writing public class DisplayTask extends TaskSim

Comment: What does `DisplayTask` have to do with the question? This is the first you have mentioned it. I suggest you try out the code in my answer, and closely read through the two Java Tutorial pages I linked. I'm taking a break. Please try to provide a **complete** picture of the question you are asking.

Comment: So far you have failed to adequately convey the question. I'm not a mind reader. More reading to hopefully help you ask a better question: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Cheers for trying to help anyways, Ill look at the tutorials.